# Finder resets preferences on restart

Tags: macos, finder, preferences

Im on macOS Sierra 10.12.5. I have customized a few things (finder window's toolbar, how to keep directories ordered by name etc) but sometimes (I think on restart, not sure) all this goes back to factory settings and I have to do it all over again. It is really annoying.

It seems people had this problem on older versions too but I prefer to ask again since it was like 4 years ago.

What can I do to prevent this? Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide details of your startup disk (i.e. capacity, free space)?

Comment: @Monomeeth I had plenty of free space (100Go at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible your Finder preference file is corrupted.

Open **Finder**, then press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>. In the popup textbox, type in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Locate `com.apple.finder.plist` and delete it. Restart your system and see if the issue persists. If it does, you can pull the file back out of the Trash and restart one more time.

Comment: I don't know why the file was corrupted in the first place but this worked. Thanks!